# How to add "new line" keyboard shortcuts in spyder

Tags: python, spyder

When using other editors, most of them have a function about "new line".
For example, the Sublime Text, use

> Ctrl + enter

to enter new line directly whatever cursor is at end of line or not.
After checked all the setting about spyder, have no idea about this.

> Thus i want to add new feature about "new line" with
>
> Ctrl + enter
>
> To enter a new line without the cursor need to move to tail

Would you have some ideas to share me ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you want this feature to do? How is it different than just pressing "enter"?

Comment: @Blckknght Thank you,modified

Comment: @VicYu Would you accept an option for `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`? It's because `ctrl` + `enter` is already used for "Run cell". You could rebind it in your own copy of Spyder anyways, I'm just putting here an answer that doesn't mess too much with Spyder's functionality as it is.

Comment: @Roberto Thank you ,excellent!You're a genius!Key is fine,importance is the feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just a Spyder user, but yes you can add such a functionality yourself. For this you need to modify the file `codeeditor.py`, which in Windows is under `\spyderlib\widgets\sourcecode\codeeditor.py`.

#### WARNING: Backup the codeeditor.py file before modifying it.

What you need to do is to modify the `keyPressEvent` function that starts at line 2129 (in my Spyder 2.3.1).

You'll see that one of the first conditionals takes care of enter/return keypresses: line 2139, `if key in (Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Return):`

The option `ctrl+Enter` is already taken... so without messing too much with the options, I'm just going to put here an option for `ctrl+shift+Enter`, which is free to use. Is this ok?

So what you want to do is to add, *after* the option `if not shift and not ctrl:`, another option with shift and control pressed; i.e. in my case I would add this at line 2153, with indentation to match the `if not shift and not ctrl:` line:

```
elif shift and ctrl: # Insert newline functionality
    cursor = self.textCursor() 
    startpos = cursor.position() # Remember where the cursor is
    self.stdkey_end(False, False) # Go to the end of the line
    self.insert_text(self.get_line_separator()) # Add a newline
    cursor.setPosition(startpos) # Go back to the initial position
    self.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

Now close Spyder, and reopen it. Try the `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter` combination in the editor, and you should get a new line just below the line you're in, as you wanted.

If you don't mind rebinding or eliminating the "Run cell" functionality in your own copy of Spyder, you could even play around and put this code under the `elif ctrl:` condition, then you'd have the `ctrl`+`enter` binding just like in Sublime Text.

Comment: Yeah ,these are something different between 2.3.1 and 2.3.2.But your post is so clear and easy-understand.I implemented this feature with your genius ,Thank you .

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Beware that your changes to `codeeditor.py` will be erased every time you update Spyder. If you want to this functionality as part of Spyder, please open an issue in our issue tracker so we can add this code directly to our own.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue writing in the new line (move the cursor there) instead of only adding a new line and keep the cursor where it is, just ignore the related lines in the accepted answer:

```
elif shift and ctrl: # Insert newline functionality
    cursor = self.textCursor() 
    # startpos = cursor.position() # optional
    self.stdkey_end(False, False) # Go to the end of the line
    self.insert_text(self.get_line_separenter code hereator()) # Add a newline
    # cursor.setPosition(startpos) # optional
    # self.setTextCursor(cursor) # optional
```

I'am going to do a pull request on this, since I guess many others can profit from this keybinding as well. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to help you:
use right shift key as End+Enter

First : sudo apt-get install xdotool

In settings, open keyboard and add a custom shortcut

name : New_line

command : xdotool key End KP_Enter

then click the 'disabled' and type R_shift key

Now you can use right shift to achieve what you want !