# Pasting multiiple lines (read as single line/inputs) into Spyder console

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, console, spyder

So, say I have to take 3 inputs from the user (name, age, location):

```
Jim Halpert
30
Scranton
```

and I write the code as follows:

```
name = input()
age = input()
location = input()
```

Now, instead of typing them one by one, I just copy and paste them from a text file, but when I paste them into the console they are not read as separate inputs. In fact, they are shown as follows:

```
Jim Halpert
...: 30
...: Scranton
```

My question is: Is there any way I can make Spyder read them as separate inputs?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you find a proper solution for this issue? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

you could use .splitlines()

```
name, age, location  = input().splitlines()
print(name)
print(age)
print(location)
```

all three variables would also be stored as strings in this case. If you do math on age you would need to convert it.

```
age = int(age)
```

if all the inputs were ints for example you could do

```
x, y, z = [int(x) for x in input().splitlines()]
```

Comment: That would work. Thanks. TBH though, I was hoping there was a way to make Spyder recognize a new line as an Enter press.

Comment: @TarabasZaratin the following link may guide you in the right direction. I have not tried this myself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182566/how-to-add-new-line-keyboard-shortcuts-in-spyder#:~:text=Try%20the%20ctrl%20%2B%20shift%20%2B%20enter,re%20in%2C%20as%20you%20wanted.